# Printing a particular text in 2-D array using foreach loop only

Tags: php

given array is

```
$info=array("sanjay"=>array("male",20),
            "ravi"=>array("male",20),
            "rahul;"=>array("male",26),
            "tina"=>array("male",21),
            "sanjna"=>array("female",60)
            );
```

output should looks like this--

```
Name is: Sanjay Sex is: male and Age is: 20
Name is: ravi Sex is: male and Age is: 20
Name is: rahul Sex is: male and Age is: 26
Name is: tina y Sex is: female and Age is: 21
Name is: Sanjna Sex is: female and Age is: 60
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a [`foreach`](http://php.net/foreach) loop would be optimal in this case:

```
foreach($info as $name => $more_info)
{
   printf("Name is: %s Sex is: %s and Age is: %d<br />", $name, $more_info[0], $more_info[1]);
}
```